# Do I need to create a DocumentBuilderFactory everytime?

Tags: java

I need to update the news feeds  for every 5 minutes from a RSS feed .

I have written a TimerTask as shown below

```
public class TimerTaskForAllNews 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        TimerTask task = new AllNewsUpdatrUtility();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000,60000);
    }
}
```

This is my TimerTask implementation class

```
package com.util;
import java.net.URL;
public class AllNewsUpdatrUtility extends TimerTask {
      private static AllNewsUpdatrUtility instance = null;
       public AllNewsUpdatrUtility() {}
       public static AllNewsUpdatrUtility getInstance() {
          if (instance == null)
             instance = new AllNewsUpdatrUtility();
          return instance;
       }
    @Override
    public void run() {
         try {
             JSONArray latestnews = new JSONArray();
             JSONObject jsonobj_allnews = new JSONObject();
             DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
             URL url = new URL("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8160628/rss.xml");
             Document doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
             NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
                String title = getValue(item, "title");
                String link = getValue(item, "link");
                String pub_date = getValue(item, "pubDate");

            } // for loop ends here 

          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }


}
```

Could you please let me know i can improve this program anyway ?

Comment: DBF ist not thread-safe. If you can guarantee it's only be used by one thread, you can cache it.

Comment: But newDocumentBuilder() is supposed to be thread-safe: https://jaxp.java.net/docs/spec/html/#plugabililty-thread-safety. So it's OK to create a DBF once and for all, and reuse it from multiple threads to create document builders.

Comment: So what? newDocumentBuilder() is not a setter method. It doesn't configure the factory. So you can create a factory and configure it from **one** thread, and then publish it so that any thread can call its newDocumentBuilder() method concurrently, because newDocumentBuilder() is thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification [JSR 206 Java™ API for XML Processing (JAXP) 1.4](https://jaxp.java.net/docs/spec/html) says:

> It is expected that the newSAXParser method of a SAXParserFactory implementation, the newDocumentBuilder method of a DocumentBuilderFactory and the newTransformer method of a TransformerFactory will be thread safe without side effects.

As said in the comment you can cache the DocumentBuilderFactory instance :

```
package com.util;
import java.net.URL;
public class AllNewsUpdatrUtility extends TimerTask {
       private static AllNewsUpdatrUtility instance;
       private final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
       private AllNewsUpdatrUtility() {}
       public synchronized static AllNewsUpdatrUtility getInstance() {
          if (instance == null)
             instance = new AllNewsUpdatrUtility();
             dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          return instance;
       }
    @Override
    public void run() {
         try {
             JSONArray latestnews = new JSONArray();
             JSONObject jsonobj_allnews = new JSONObject();
             DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
             URL url = new URL("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8160628/rss.xml");
             Document doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
             NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
                String title = getValue(item, "title");
                String link = getValue(item, "link");
                String pub_date = getValue(item, "pubDate");

            } // for loop ends here 

          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }


}
```

Comment: This is far from being thread-safe though: the constructor should be private, the dbf shouldn't be static: it should be final and initialized in the constructor, and the getInstance() method should be synchronized.

Comment: @JBNizet The OP didn't ask for a thread safe class but you are totally right. I've included your suggestions.